# How can I style v-slot:cell templates?

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have the following template in a table:

```
    <template v-slot:cell(checkbox)="row" style="border-left='5px dotted blue'">                      
       <input type="checkbox" v-model="row.rowSelected" @input="toggleSelectRow(row)"/>             
    </template>
```

I'm trying to do inline styling on the template so that I can eventually assign a fading border after the form has been submitted.  That said, I'm struggling to get even basic styling happening.

I am using bootstrap-vue, but my understanding is that I can inject regular CSS as well.

How can I get a simple border around my cell?

Answer (score 3):

You sadly can't apply styles or classes to a `<template>`.

You have a few options to work around this.

Firstly, by using the [fields](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#fields-column-definitions) property on `b-table`.
You can use this to remove the default padding in a column, by using the utility class `p-0`, which you will add to the [tdClass](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#field-definition-reference) property on your field object. You can then wrap your `b-checkbox` in a div, and apply the padding back to this element.

This will allow you to style your checkbox wrapper div as if it was the cell.

Another option using the `tdClass` option in the `fields` object to apply classes with your styles. The great thing about `tdClass` is your can bind a method to it, which passes in information about that cells value. Meaning you can change the classes applied based on the content of the cell.

The last option, is to use [b-table-simple](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#simple-tables) and write the markup yourself. This of course allows you full freedom over the table, but you lose all the fancy functionality of `b-table` and will have to add that back yourself.

---

Here's a snippet of how you could implement option 1 and 2.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      fields: [
        'age',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        {
          key: 'active',
          tdClass: 'p-0'
        },
        {
          key: 'active2',
          tdClass: this.applyTdClass
        }
      ],
      items: [{
          age: 40,
          first_name: 'Dickerson',
          last_name: 'Macdonald',
          active: false,
          active2: false
        },
        {
          age: 21,
          first_name: 'Larsen',
          last_name: 'Shaw',
          active: false,
          active2: false
        },
        {
          age: 89,
          first_name: 'Geneva',
          last_name: 'Wilson',
          active: true,
          active2: true
        },
        {
          age: 38,
          first_name: 'Jami',
          last_name: 'Carney',
          active: false,
          active2: false
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    applyTdClass(value, key, item) {
      const classes = [];

      classes.push('border');
      /* Example of dynamically changing classes */
      if (value) {
        classes.push('bg-success');
      } else {
        classes.push('bg-danger');
      }

      return classes;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.13.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.13.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <b-table :items="items" :fields="fields">
    <template v-slot:cell(active)="{ item }">
      <div style="padding: 0.75rem" class="border-left border-primary">
      <b-checkbox v-model="item.active"></b-checkbox>      
      </div>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:cell(active2)="{ item }">
      <b-checkbox v-model="item.active2"></b-checkbox>
    </template>
  </b-table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Hiws!  Working on it!!